# How can I find primitive axis for any bulk or 2D (monolayer) material

Tags: vasp, phonopy, dfpt

I am doing `DFPT` calculations using `VASP+Phonopy`.
To plot phonon band structure, I need a band.conf file in which we need to provide  `primitive axis`.
There is an option to use `--pa=auto` but in my case, it is not working, or maybe for `DFPT`, we need to supply a proper `primitive axis`.

Is there any way or code using which we can know the primitive axis of any system?

`POSCAR` for my system is mentioned below:

```
System                                  
   1.00000000000000     
     5.2830000000000004    0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000
     0.0000000000000000    5.2830000000000004    0.0000000000000000
     0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000   20.0000000000000000
   Ta   N 
     2     4
Direct
  0.0000000038778781 -0.0000000040248837  0.4999999999997483
  0.5000000098083184  0.4999999954548999  0.4999999998722517
  0.1428654795841584  0.6428651637231821  0.5338481609868386
  0.8571345120369003  0.3571348472078131  0.5338481661924134
  0.6428651606314468  0.8571345203839439  0.4661518370931707
  0.3571348450612953  0.1428654882550420  0.4661518358555774
```

Comment: The documentation says that the primitive axis is the transformation matrix from the primitive cell to the supercell and that it is optional. Are you wanting help defining this matrix using software or help with getting the automatic primitive cell detection in phonopy to work? If it’s the latter, maybe a description of the error message or a minimal example that demonstrates the issue would help get an answer.

Comment: Yes, I want to define pimitive_axis to get the phonon band structure. Please let me know if I need to supply some information from my side.

Comment: Are you sure that your cell is not already a primitive cell?

Comment: Yes, it is already a primitive cell. This is just an example. I am focusing to get a permanent solution to get the primitive axis to get the phonon band structure of any structure.

Comment: @astha just to be clear: you are looking for a code that, given a general cell, will output the corresponding primitive cell?

Comment: `ATOM_NAME=Ta N`
`DIM = 2 2 1`
`PRIMITIVE_AXIS="auto"`
`#PRIMITIVE_AXIS=0.0 0.5 0.0  0.0 -0.5 0.0  0.0 0.0 0.5`
`BAND = 0.00000000  0.00000  0.0000  0.50000  0.000 0.0000  0.50000000   0.50000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.00000000   0.000`

`BAND_LABELS= $\Gamma$ X M $\Gamma$`

`FORCE_CONSTANTS = READ`
`FORCE_CONSTANTS = WRITE`
`GROUP_VELOCITY = .TRUE.`

You see here, I am using `PRIMITIVE_AXIS="auto"`. In many cases, `PRIMITIVE_AXIS` works well but in some cases, it does not work. So I am looking for a code which at given input file provides us `PRIMITIVE_AXIS`.

Comment: astha, thanks for replying to all comments so quickly! Perhaps you can put some of the `code` block in that comment, into the question so that it's easier for @ProfM to read? `code` blocks (especially long ones) tend to be displayed in a much clearer way when they're in actual posts rather than just in comments.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if the OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments or anyone else wants to give an answer.